# Is there a programming language to create a UML diagram?

Tags: uml, programming-languages

I am looking for a programming language like Latex(for documents) to create UML diagrams. Is there a language where we can provide a set of commands to create a UML diagram.

Answer (score 7):

There is a standard from the OMG called the [Abstract Language for Foundational UML](http://www.omg.org/spec/ALF/). It *is* UML, in a textual form. You can define classes as well as activities.

There are a couple of implementations. There's the [reference implementation](https://github.com/ModelDriven/Alf-Reference-Implementation) and a [Papyrus implementation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus/UserGuide/fUML_ALF). More implementations are in the works.

Besides that, try this list of [textual UML tools](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual).

Answer (score 3):

Using [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/), you can write a plain text description and it will give you a UML diagram.  It's not a programming language (no conditional/looping constructs), more of a declarative language like SQL.  It's built on top of the [GraphViz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) tool, which uses the "DOT" language for specifying generic diagrams.

You write things like:

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response

Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: another authentication Response
@enduml
```

Run it through the processor and end up with a diagram like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Latex with : [TikZ-UML](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uml-diagrams-with-tikz-uml/ftfzzpmwnjqw)

You can also use markdown with [markdown plus](https://mdp.tylingsoft.com/#class-diagram) propulsed by [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/).

[image: class diagram in md]

````
```mermaid
classDiagram
Class01 <|-- AveryLongClass : Cool
Class03 *-- Class04
Class05 o-- Class06
Class07 .. Class08
Class09 --> C2 : Where am i?
Class09 --* C3
Class09 --|> Class07
Class07 : equals()
Class07 : Object[] elementData
Class01 : size()
Class01 : int chimp
Class01 : int gorilla
Class08 <--> C2: Cool label
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Visual Studio and when you code your classes our you can right click on the class and "View Class Diagram".  Visual Studio will do all the work for you.  I am unsure of other Integrated Development Environments, as I am in the .NET world.

Answer (score 0):

XML Metadata Interchange (XMI) may be a good fit for your needs.  Check out [http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701/PrimitiveTypes.xmi "OMG's XMI definition of UML primitive types"](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701/PrimitiveTypes.xmi) as an example.